# json_encode() doesn't display arabic characters in good way

Tags: php, json, arabic

i have problem with Arabic characters when i do json_encode() it always return ????, in the database all the fields and database is utf8

my code:

```
$query   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Names`");

if (!$query) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
die($message);
}else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {
     $result[] = array(
        'Mid' => $row['Mid'], 
        'Uid' => $row['Uid'], 
        'Cid' => $row['Cid'], 
        'Name' => $row['Name'],
        'city' => $row['city'],
        'status' => $row['status'],
        'Mobile' => $row['Mobile'],
        'Phone' => $row['Phone'],
        'Email' => $row['Email']);
    }
      header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
      echo json_encode($result);
}
```

the result look like:

```
[{"Mid":"17","Uid":"1","Cid":"8","Name":"???? ?? ??????? ?? ???","city":"?????",
```

please help me

Comment: Are you sure the data is actually encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: @Gumbo yes i'm sure ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706846/unable-to-store-arabic-in-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: Do you set the connection encoding when you connect to MySQL?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No i dont set it, but now i set it and it's work fine  Thanks,  mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

Comment: And just in case, check if your data are stored as hex values

Comment: Please do not the deprecated mysql_ functions, use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead!

Comment: Oh i missed the word "use" in my comment. :( For clarity: 
Please **do not use** the deprecated mysql_ functions, use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead!

Comment: Thanks @Otanaught, i know that but this project it just prototype :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this before sending your query

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

or this (if your PHP version is 5.4.0 or above)

```
json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Note: In case that your data are stored in hex format, enclose `json_encode` with `mysql_escape_string()`.